# Maya SDK Conversion between Rotation Anim curve to Quaternion

Tags: maya

so I have a specific question on the Maya SDK API, as documentation on this is quite poor.

So I have extracted at a particular key frame, the X, Y, and Z angle on the respect Rotation AnimCurves.

I am, however unsure how to properly convert this to a Quaternion, as
the order of X, Y, and Z could be dependent on the person using Maya.

Thanks

Comment: mayas docs are quite good. The old docs were structured better tough. Anyway fetch the transform and ask what the rotation order is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- I managed to fix the issue, and I posted it below. Took quite a while to properly extract all the skin / animation / model into my format. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway after many hours of debugging I did a work around to fix the bug.

It seems that a given animcurves of a bone does not
necessarily give the bones local transform -- which is what I thought it did

The XYZ angles it gave me back were its global rotation -- which
really wrecked me.

In order to extract the local quaternion, this seemed to work:

Loop over all keyFrameTimes

```
Use MAnimControl::setCurrentTime  to the keyTime

localMatrix = jointPath.inclusiveMatrix() * jointPath.exclusiveMatrixInverse();

from this matrix extract the Translation/Rotation/Scale out,
and it seems to work fine
```

End